# Task Manager shows more threads than I've created

Tags: c++, multithreading

In my C++ application I'm creating four threads. But my task manager shows that the process has 17 or so. Where do these threads come from? Are they affecting my performance? If so, how do I terminate them?

**EDIT:** I'm using Visual Studio 2012.
**EDIT 2:** I just see that my application seems to be creating and terminating threads on it's own. What is happening?

Comment: what environment are you using?

Comment: can you take as through the steps you are taking to see those 17 threads?

Comment: I'm opening the task manager->"Performance"-Tab->Resource Monitor->RAM

Comment: Ho do you know they belong to your application?

Comment: Because they are displayed on the process of my application.

Comment: and what about the environment?

Comment: is it a VS app you built? gcc?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45652/discussion-between-liess-jemai-and-pandrei)

Comment: no time to do that but try using process Explorer to get more info

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking StackOverflow to debug your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain APIs create and manage threads on their own in the background. For example, if you use Win32 multimedia timers, the APIs will create a few threads for timer related activities. So if you see threads that you aren't explicitly creating, they're probably being created and managed by the APIs you are using.

Comment: I see also see this file dialogs and network access on windows (well at least when I use Qt). Although to me I do not worry about the # of threads my application has especially the ones that are out of my control.